# Call a future method on Provider initialization

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

How can one call a method from a provider on initialization?

Want to call `CoolProvider().fetchCoolData()`

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => CoolProvider(),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          SomeWidgetWithConsumer(),
          AnotherWidgetWithConsumer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => CoolProvider()..fetchCoolData(),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          SomeWidgetWithConsumer(),
          AnotherWidgetWithConsumer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Nice! Tried doing it with 1 dot and it didn't work. What does the second dot do?

Comment: Nice job Jigar, this is pretty slick. I didn’t think of that :)

Comment: You can read about the double dots (cascade notation) here - https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-

Comment: Also, how can I know whether the data is loading in a consumer?

Comment: For that, you can have a `bool` variable `loading` in `CoolProvider`. And inside `fetchCoolData` method, you can make it true at start and false after `await` (which means after data is fetched). And whenever you change `loading` to true or false, call `notifyListeners()` in the next line so all the `Consumer`s which are listening to this particular `ChangeNotifier` will be notified of the change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you’re trying to fetch something, it’s probably a `Future`. If that’s the case you can simply wrap the child of the `ChangeNotifierProvider` with a `FutureBuilder`. Check out the flutter docs to find out how to use it!